# session_start() nevers return if requested with fetch API

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, session-cookies

I am experiencing a problem but only with Google Chrome/Edge. My code works fine with Firefox.
The problem:

```
    <?php
    $sessionRs = session_start();
    var_dump($sessionRs);
    ?>
    <button onclick="fetch('fail.php', { method: 'POST' }).then();">Test</button>
```

When you click on the button, the page will load but its loaded with the fetchAPI instead of the browser directly.

On Firefox, in the developpement tools section, in the "Network" tab, the request is successful and can be previewed (looks the same as the one loaded directly).

On Google Chrome and Edge, the request never ends. The session_start() never ends.

Thanks in advance for helping.

I tried different browser and looked at the sent cookies and it seems the cookies are sent even in Google Chrome but the PHP never answer anyway. I didn't see any error in the apache's log.

Comment: I took your code exactly as-is, nothing else, and saved it as "failed.php". When I test it in Chrome is see `bool(true)` followed by the button. When I press the button I see a fetch performed. So it appears to be doing something, although I'm not really clear what you expect from this.

Comment: Yes, but for me, the fetch never ends. In the 'Timing' tab when selecting the request, it's writen 'CAUTION: request is not finished yet'